# Extra space of extended partition is not used

Tags: partitioning, vmware

So I have a virtual machine and my guest is missing space. So I increased its VM disk size and now I want it to dispose of that extra space. I've extended the partition using GParted (from inside the guest) and it sort of worked. I had an error message but the partition did increase in size. cryptdata has the correct disk size but data-root has not, I fear this is the problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is the result of fdisk and df (I increased to 100GB from 50GB):

```
15:34:16 ~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for aho: 
Disk /dev/sda: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Disk model: VMware Virtual S
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb1032965

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         4096   1023998   1019903  498M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2         1024000 201326591 200302592 95.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       201326592 209715199   8388608    4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/mapper/cryptdata: 95.51 GiB, 102538149888 bytes, 200269824 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/data-root: 45.5 GiB, 48846864384 bytes, 95404032 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
15:34:34 ~$ sudo df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                   5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                  1.2G  3.1M  1.2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/data-root   45G   31G   12G  73% /
tmpfs                  5.9G  4.0M  5.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                  5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1              467M  332M  101M  77% /boot
vmhgfs-fuse            489G  293G  197G  60% /mnt/hgfs
tmpfs                  1.2G   16K  1.2G   1% /run/user/110
tmpfs                  1.2G   24K  1.2G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sr0               2.6G  2.6G     0 100% /media/aho/Pop_OS 20.10 amd64 Nvidia
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've found the issue and the solution. The issue is that only the physical volume was extended. I had to extend the logical volume as well and it seems that either GParted doesn't do that or it failed because I booted on the partition I wanted to reboot.

So, first, I made a second virtual machine to which I added the disk of the problematic machine to be able to manage its disk without booting it. Somehow, I couldn't boot on CD/USB of the first virtual machine, it wouldn't show up.

Then I followed the section "Increasing the logical volume" of the following guide: https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-increase-the-size-of-a-linux-lvm-by-expanding-the-virtual-machine-disk/.

Comment: For anyone wondering how to extend the logical volume: `lvm` -> `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/name-of-volume-group/root` -> `sudo resize2fs /dev/name-of-volume-group/root`